# Ruby on Rails active_record: when child is saved, the parent select query is occurred. why and how can I avoid this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

```
class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
end

class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children
end

irb(main):073:0> child = Child.last
  Child Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "children".* FROM "children" ORDER BY "children"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
+----+----------------------+-----------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| id | title                | parent_id | created_at                | updated_at                |
+----+----------------------+-----------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| 1  | this is childs title | 1         | 2018-08-23 12:09:37 +0900 | 2018-08-23 12:09:37 +0900 |
+----+----------------------+-----------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
1 row in set
irb(main):074:0> child.save
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  Parent Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "parents".* FROM "parents" WHERE "parents"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

Code is like this. 
When I save the child, the parent select query is occurred.
I don't know why this is happended, and is it possible to avoid this?

In my case, the parent has many columns and big, so it is memory expensive to load it automatically.

Comment: Can you show how do you make `child` object before save it.?

Comment: @Gabbar Thanks for rapid comment!. This is what I made child. `child = parent.children.new(title: 'this is childs title')`

Answer (score 0):

In this way you can avoid to call parent before save child

```
Child.new(title: 'this is childs title', parent_id: parent.id)
```

Comment: Yes. it does not trigger the select query. what is the difference? can I get some reference link of this?

Comment: @kikiki.blue Actually when this query fires `parent.children.new` first it fetches `parent` which causes select `parent` query first before creating object of child. thanks for accept answer :)

Comment: What do you think about this? I guess that my question is not cleared yet. :) `irb(main):006:0> child = Child.find 1
  Child Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "children".* FROM "children" WHERE "children"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
1 row in set
irb(main):007:0> child.save
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  Parent Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "parents".* FROM "parents" WHERE "parents"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
=> true` It still load parent in this common find and save action.

Comment: I am sorry @Gabbar. I think that I did not understand why the parent select query should be occurred yet. just find the child and save method occurr the parent select query.